# FadeInImage in CircleAvatar

Tags: flutter

How can I have a fade in effect in `CircleAvatar`?
Type of `backgroundImage` of `CircleAvatar` is `ImageProvider` and `FadeInImage` is not a `ImageProvider`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Clip react,
for image loading i use CachedNetworkImage(cached_network_image: 2.3.3)

```
       ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset('loadder.gif'),
                    imageUrl:
                        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRLe5PABjXc17cjIMOibECLM7ppDwMmiDg6Dw&usqp=CAU"),
              ),
```

this is user loader image or gif(example).

```
placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset('loadder.gif'),
```

this is your main image(example).

```
imageUrl:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRLe5PABjXc17cjIMOibECLM7ppDwMmiDg6Dw&usqp=CAU"),
```